# Magento 2 : Catalog Price Rule Based On Time Period

Tags: magento2, discount, catalog-price-rules

I have come across a requirement where my client wants to provide a discount on specific products which is based on time period. Below is the condition.

- Discount Start - Every day after 22:00 Hrs
- Discount Ends - Next day    on 06:00 Hrs

How I can achieve this in magento2?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This feature will be added in Magento's 2.3 version.
See in [documentation](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/price-rule-catalog-scheduled-changes.html)